# Does the program execution always start from main in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pragma, preprocessor-directive

Must program execution start from main, or can the starting address be modified?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun();

#pragma startup fun

int main()
{
    printf("in main");
    return 0;
}

void fun()
{
    printf("in fun");
}
```

This program prints `in fun` before `in main`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use pragma startup preprocessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617005/how-do-you-use-pragma-startup-preprocessor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The '#pragma' command is specified in the ANSI standard to have an arbitrary implementation-defined effect. In the GNU C preprocessor, '#pragma' first attempts to run the game 'rogue'; if that fails, it tries to run the game 'hack'; if that fails, it tries to run GNU Emacs displaying the Tower of Hanoi; if that fails, it reports a fatal error. In any case, preprocessing does not continue.

**-- Richard M. Stallman, The GNU C Preprocessor, version 1.34**

Program execution starts at the startup code, or "runtime". This is usually some assembler routine called `_start` or somesuch, located (on Unix machines) in a file `crt0.o` that comes with the compiler package. It does the setup required to run a C executable (like, setting up `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, the vectors used by `atexit()`... for C++ it also includes initializing of global objects, i.e. running their constructors). Only then does control jump to `main()`.

As the quote at the beginning of my answer expresses so eloquently, what `#pragma` does is completely up to your compiler. Check its documentation. (I'd guess your `pragma startup` - which should be prepended with a `#` by the way - tells the runtime to call `fun()` first...)

Comment: Actually I wish compiler builders had stuck with Stallman's position. It would have saved us from stupid stuff like `pragma once` or source code hard-disabling compiler warnings...

Answer (score 2):

As far as the ISO C Standard is concerned, the entry point for a C program is always `main` (unless some implementation-defined feature is used to override it) *for a hosted implementation*.  For a "freestanding implementation" (typically an embedded system, often with no operating system), the entry point is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

C programs are not necessarily start from `main()` function. Some codes are executed before `main()` that zero out all uninitialized global variables and initialize other global variables with proper value. For example, consider the following code:

```
int a;
int b = 10;

int main()
{
    int c = a * b;
    return 0;
}
```

In the example code above, `a` and `b` are assigned `0` and `10` respectively before the execution of first line in `main()`.

The `#pragma` directive is there to define implementation-defined behaviour. Your code with `#pragma` may compile in some compiler but may not compile in another.

Comment: Isn't the setting up of .data and .bss sections done by the executable loader, instead of the startup code?

Comment: @devsolar: this may not be always the case. for example micro-controllers. I've worked on OKI 411, OKI 431 and PIC16F micros. They all have some sort of startup/runtime code. btw, i don't know how these are typcially achieved when programmed for PC. i've only heard of the names `.data` and `.bss`, don't know much about them. can you please give me some link from which i can learn more?

Comment: Basic ELF object file layout: Section .text contains the machine code, .data contains initialization data (the `10` in your example). .bss is the "zero initialized" area, which of course is not in the executable, or rather only as a "size" number; you leave it to the loader to provide sufficient zero-initialized memory. Reality, of course, is more difficult (sections containing debug information, or C++ exception handling, or stuff like that). Check Wikipedia, "Data segment".